# Creating a searchable text box for an external data source linked table - VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Afternoon everyone,

I'm in the process of creating a literature database which involves MS forms for submission, Sharepoints List for collation and then MS Excel for displaying.

There are 3 broad categories and thus a corresponding sheet for each category which I'd like to have a search box on each of those 3 sheets to then search through the keywords or the literature title. The data comes from a sharepoint query so is a table and have used some VBA code but it regularly throws a run-time error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed.

Code below, is this the best way of doing it? Is there an easier method? Perhaps =filter from a centralised sheet of all 3 categories? If this is the easiest method then is there an issue in my code?

```
Option Explicit

Sub EIASearch()
'PURPOSE: Filter Data on User-Determined Column & Text
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim myButton As OptionButton
Dim MyVal As Long
Dim ButtonName As String
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myField As Long
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim mySearch As Variant
   
'Load Sheet into A Variable
  Set sht = ActiveSheet

'Unfilter Data (if necessary)
  On Error Resume Next
    sht.ShowAllData
  On Error GoTo 0
   
'Filtered Data Range (include column heading cells)
  Set DataRange = sht.Range("A5:F100") 'Cell Range
  'Set DataRange = sht.ListObjects("EIATable").Range 'Table

'Retrieve User's Search Input
  mySearch = sht.Shapes("EIABox").TextFrame.Characters.Text 'Control Form
  'mySearch = sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text 'ActiveX Control
  'mySearch = sht.Range("A1").Value 'Cell Input

'Loop Through Option Buttons
  For Each myButton In ActiveSheet.OptionButtons
      If myButton.Value = 1 Then
        ButtonName = myButton.Text
        Exit For
      End If
  Next myButton
  
'Determine Filter Field
  myField = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ButtonName, DataRange.Rows(1), 0)
  
'Filter Data
  DataRange.AutoFilter _
    Field:=myField, _
    Criteria1:="=*" & mySearch & "*", _
    Operator:=xlAnd
  
'Clear Search Field
  sht.Shapes("EIABox").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "" 'Control Form
  'sht.OLEObjects("UserSearch").Object.Text = "" 'ActiveX Control
  'sht.Range("A1").Value = "" 'Cell Input
  
End Sub
```

[Example of the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DnB9d.png)

Comment: Side note: `Operator:=xlAnd` doesn't really make sense since that's used when you have `Criteria1` and `Criteria2`, which is not the case here.

Comment: @BigBen thanks for that - removed, unfortunately not the source of the error though